# Converting a list to a tuple of lists

Tags: python, list, multiprocessing, tuples

I have a numpy ndarray which needs to be converted to a tuple of lists for multiprocessor.Pool to operate on them. I have converted this ndarray to a list shown here:

```
file_list = ['File_01', 'File_02', 'File_03']
```

In order to feed this list of files as an argument I believe I need this list to be a tuple of lists shown here:

```
tuple_of_file_names = (['File_01'], ['File_02'], ['File_03'])
```

I am interested in how to convert this list of file names to a tuple of lists of file names.

Comment: You don't need to convert the list of filenames to anything for usage with `Pool` as long as you use a `pool.map`-method (not starmap).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well if you originally had an `ndarray`, the simplest thing you can do is add another axis to it using [`np.newaxis`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/arrays.indexing.html#numpy.newaxis)/`None`  and then obtain a nested list using `tolist()`.

Here's an example:

```
x = np.array([1,2,3])

x[:, np.newaxis].tolist()
# [[1], [2], [3]]
```

---

Note: If you want the resulting list as a tuple simply call the `tuple` constructor, as `tuple(nested_list)`

Answer (score 1):

Simple comprehension will do the job:

```
tuple_of_file_names = tuple([name] for name in file_list)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `map` + `lambda` and `tuple()` to convert to tuple:

```
file_list = ['File_01', 'File_02', 'File_03']

tuple_of_file_names = tuple(map(lambda x: [x], file_list))
# (['File_01'], ['File_02'], ['File_03'])
```

Comment: `tuple([[i] for i in file_list])` is probably cleaner than using a `lambda` here

Comment: @aws_apprentice you don't even need the list comp, a generator expression would work too: tuple([i] for i in file_list)`

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`map`](http://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/map_filter.html#map) along with [`zip`](https://pythonprogramming.net/zip-intermediate-python-tutorial/) and `tuple` to get your result:

```
file_list = ['File_01', 'File_02', 'File_03']
file_list = tuple(map(list,zip(file_list)))
print(file_list)
```

Output:

```
(['File_01'], ['File_02'], ['File_03'])
```